# Implementing an algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking over some old coursework and wanted to try and implement the algorithms in code. One of the problems reads:

Given an array A with maximum M and minimum m, 
show that there is a pair of numbers `A[i], A[i+1]` so that `|A[i] - A[i-1]| <= (M-m)/(n-1)`

Should I just iterate over the input looking for pairs that fit this condition? Could someone point me in the right direction with some pseudocode perhaps?

Comment: "Show" doesn't sound like they want you to write code. It sounds like they want you to prove that such a pair must exist, given the conditions in the problem statement.

Comment: This is unclear, what are `M,m`, I assume `n` is number of elements? Where do you use `A[i+1]`?

Comment: @amit I forgot to mention and I will make this edit in a moment, but in an array A, M is a maximum and m is a minimum. n is the number of elements, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean a sorted array?

Otherwise, `[1, 3, 5, 2, 7]` doesn't conform to the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's another way, yes.

To iterate over a list in a pairwise way, you might find this function helpful:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    b = iter(iterable)
    next(b)
    yield from zip(a,b)
```

Comment: The `yield from` syntax is Python 3-exclusive; if the OP is using Python 2 they would want `for bar in zip(a,b): yield bar`